# Dúvida com a linguagem C#

Tags: c#

Tenho uma `String` qualquer tipo "cadeira ".

#### Dúvida

Como faço pra dar um espaço entre todas as letras em `C#`?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao SOpt Vinicius, você pode editar sua pergunta ao invés de escrever no campo de resposta ;) Já tem algum código escrito?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Duvidas com string em c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/325041/duvidas-com-string-em-c)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer dessa forma, verifique se é isso que você precisa.

```
string palavra = "palavra";
string nova_palavra = "";

foreach (var c in palavra)
{
    nova_palavra += c + " ";
}
nova_palavra = nova_palavra.Remove(nova_palavra.Length - 1);
Console.WriteLine(nova_palavra);
```

Veja o exemplo rodando aqui:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/YOkaVY

Comment: Essa solução deixa um espaço adicional no final da palavra Thiago.

Comment: pronto @GustavoSantos, tirei o espaço lá :) Obrigado!

Comment: também atende, tem diversas formas de fazer, inclusive a que você postou, como é um problema muito simples as formas de resolver são inúmeras..

Answer (score 2):

Existe outra forma de fazer o mesmo:

```
string palavra = "palavra";
string palavaComEspacos = string.Join(" ", palavra.ToCharArray());

Console.WriteLine(palavaComEspacos);
```

Nessa solução, o resultado é exatamente o que você busca, o método ToCharArray retorna um array de todos os caracteres da string, e o string.Join une esse array utilizando um espaço (primeiro parâmetro).

Além disso, o Join utiliza o StringBuilder, o que evita sobrecarga do Garbage Colletor, você pode encontrar a implementação do método na documentação oficial: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/string.cs

DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bwUjWi