# Colocar espaços entre letras de um texto

Tags: c#, .net, string

Como que uma determinada `string` como "Alguma coisa" ficasse com espaços entre as letras como por exemplo "A l g u m a  C o i s a"; como eu faço isso em C#?

Comment: É para todas as palavras se transforarem em maiúsculo? O que acontece com o espaço em branco já existente? E se tiver espaço no início ou fim da frase? Sem saber onde que chegar qualquer caminho é válido e aí não é uma pergunta válida para este site, precisamos de perguntas com critérios definidos e que possa existir uma resposta certa.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Dúvida com a linguagem C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/324350/d%c3%bavida-com-a-linguagem-c)

Comment: Você já fez a pergunta em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/324350/d%C3%BAvida-com-a-linguagem-c/324372#324372 na pergunta já existem respostas que abordam o mesmo assunto e que tratam os problemas de eficiência citados em demais respostas de forma mais elegante.

Answer (score 3):

As duas respostas atuais estão com problemas e não produzem o resultado esperado, pelo menos não em todas situações e conforme o exemplo mostrado na pergunta. Se uma dessas respostas estiver certa então a pergunta está errada.

Deveria evitar problemas com espaços extras colocados. Se por acaso não precise cuidar dos espaços em branco dá para simplificar o código (se o AP se pronunciar eu posso por uma versão mais simples), mas ainda é muito melhor fazer a forma eficiente que é o motivo principal de eu ter postado. Acho ruim opções que ensinam fazer de forma ineficiente (pelo menos deveria ter um alerta)

Além disto há ineficiência em ambas por gerar várias alocações de *string* que é algo que vai gerar muita pressão no *garbage collector*, o que importa muito em *strings* que são consideradas lentas quando comparadas com manipulações de números e que frequentemente são usadas em laços o que faz uma diferença enorme em grandes volumes. Deve usar [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netcore-2.1).

Assim me parece mais correto:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Text;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var frase = " Alguma coisa ";
        var espacado = new StringBuilder(frase.Length * 2 - 1);
        var i = 0;
        for (; i < frase.Length && frase[i] == ' '; i++);
        espacado.Append(char.ToUpper(frase[i]));
        for (i++; i < frase.Length; i++) {
            if (frase[i] != ' ') {
                espacado.Append(' ');
                espacado.Append((i == 0 || frase[i - 1] == ' ') ? char.ToUpper(frase[i]) : char.ToLower(frase[i]));
            }
        }
        WriteLine("|" + espacado + "|");
    }
}
```

Eu não gosto muito de *flag*, quase sempre é gambiarra ou preguiça de achar a forma correta, ou até falha da linguagem em poder expressar aquilo, mas neste caso acho que simplifica o código:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Text;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var frase = " Alguma coisa ";
        var espacado = new StringBuilder(frase.Length * 2 - 1);
        var primeiro = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < frase.Length; i++) {
            if (frase[i] == ' ') continue;
            if (!primeiro) {
                espacado.Append(' ');
            }
            primeiro = false;
            espacado.Append((i == 0 || frase[i - 1] == ' ') ? char.ToUpper(frase[i]) : char.ToLower(frase[i]));
        }
        WriteLine("|" + espacado + "|");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LFjGNL), E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vXU41o). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/PutSpaces.cs) (e a [segunda forma](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/PutSpaces2.cs)).

Comment: Votei +1 na sua reposta. Percebi que o `StringBuilder` é mais rápido e é uma boa abordagem.

Comment: Sim, mas o certo nessa pergunta era ninguém ter respondido, olha a bagunça que isso virou. Por isso que eu acho que precisa fechar certas coisas logo, ou quando foi tarde demais, desconsiderar o que foi respondido, a ferramenta é errada e incentiva muito respostas sem ter condições de responder.

Comment: Concordo, este foi o erro primordial que eu cometi, eu havia conversado com o pessoal no chat e estava cogitando excluir minha resposta. Mas olhando por outro ângulo, sua reposta pode ajudar outras pessoas, e a minha reforça ao menos. Nas próximas vez vou ter mais cautela e fechar logo para evitar essas coisas ;)

Comment: Já tinha uma resposta.

Answer (score 1):

No Linq há o método [Select](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2) que permite a você projetar cada elemento de uma sequencia. Lembre-se que uma string nada mais é do que uma sequencia de caracteres.

Veja um exemplo:

```
var str = "Alguma coisa";
var r = string.Concat(str.Select((s) => " " + s.ToString()));
Write(r);
```

Saída:

> A l g u m a   c o i s a

Ele busca os elementos da `string`, o que eu fiz foi concatenar com um espaço em branco `" "` com o elemento atual e como o `Select` método retorna um enumerável a gente usa o [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd991828(v=vs.110).aspx) para concatenar todos em uma `string` só.

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jF4Orc).

---

## Edição

Foi uma falha minha não ter percebido que tem que manter as primeiras letras em maiúscula de cada palavra. Sendo assim, criei uma nova versão corrigindo esta falha e com algumas modificações.

Veja o código:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Linq;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {     
        var str = "  Alguma coisa outrA i   i coIsA ";

        var resultado = Espacar(RemoverTodosEspacos(Capitalizar(str, false, "pt-BR")));
        Write($"|{resultado}|");        
    }

    private static string Capitalizar(string texto, bool acronimo, string cultura) { 
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(texto) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cultura)) {
            return null;
        }
        TextInfo info = new CultureInfo(cultura, false).TextInfo;       
        if (acronimo) {
            return info.ToTitleCase(texto);
        }
        return info.ToTitleCase(texto.ToLower());
    }

    private static string Espacar(string texto) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(texto)) {
            return null;
        }       
        return string.Concat(texto.Select((s, i) => " " + s.ToString())).TrimStart();
    }

    private static string RemoverTodosEspacos(string texto) { 
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(texto)) { 
            return null;
        }
        return Regex.Replace(texto, @"\s+", "");
    }
}
```

Saída

> |A l g u m a C o i s a O u t r a I I C o i s a|

A primeira coisa que tem que fazer é uma *capitalização* na `string` para garantir que as primeiras letras sejam maiúsculas. O método que faz isso é o [ToTitleCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.110).aspx) da classe `TextInfo`, e para considerar o uso de acrônimos e [culturas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ky2chs3h(v=vs.110).aspx) criei o método `Capitalizar()` que permite definir qual cultura será, ou se vai ignorar os acrônimos.

Eu assumi que o AP só quer um espaço entre as letras ou caracteres, então criei um método `RemoverTodosEspacos()` para remover todos espaços em branco da string e os TABs que contiver na `string`, e este método usa uma expressão regular.

E por fim criei o método `Espacar()` que é a mesma abordagem acima, com a diferença de que ele remove o espaço no inicio da `string` e faz a checagem se a string é valida.

Veja o novo código funcionando no **[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LkEwPI)**.

## Importante

A abordagem acima pode não ser tão performática quanto a abordagem do [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/325264/27190).

O `StringBuilder` é mais rápido e você pode comparar [aqui](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/306822/how-to-improve-string-concatenation-performance-in-visual-c) e [ler mais aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder). Claro que se performance for a prioridade devido ao volume de dados e a quantidade de mudanças que vai ocorrer na `string` eu fortemente recomendo você adotar a abordagem do Maniero.

Também não fiz todos os teste no código que criei e ele precisa de melhorias, até mesmo em questão de performance ou possíveis anomalias que podem vir a ocorrer. Sendo assim, sugiro que você melhore ele e se aprofunde mais no assunto.

Fontes:

[Converting string to title case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206019/converting-string-to-title-case)

[Efficient way to remove ALL whitespace from String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219454/efficient-way-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-string)

Answer (score 0):

Faça um `foreach` que vai ler cada posição dessa `string`, exemplo:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string frase = "Alguma coisa".Replace(" ","");
        string result = "";
        foreach(var f in frase) {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) result += " ";
            result += f;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

[Exemplo OnLine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iNavV8)

Cada item lido dessa `string` é um `char` e com isso você pode montar um nova `string` com os espaços.

Comment: Só gostaria de entender o voto negativo? tem alguma coisa errada que eu não vi?

Comment: cara, acredito que o autor da pergunta é bem leigo em C#, pela pontuação acredito também que essa deve ser a primeira pergunta dele no SO-pt, logo quem for que seja a pessoa a responder, se fizer uso de algum estrutura ou método, seria bom a pessoa explicar o que cada um faz. Eu nunca precisei fazer isso, mas entendi pois mexo com C# há um tempo já, mas olhando por uma outra perspectiva(a do novato no caso), tu mais fez do que explicou. abs!

Comment: @LuckasFujimoto isso não justifica levar um voto negativo. Em nenhum momento também a resposta está tão complicada pra entender, é a maneira mais simples de fazer a outra resposta utilizou Linq imagine você muito mais complicado.

Comment: foi exatamente por isso que eu dei upvote na sua resposta. Pois se for considerar o que está em cada método, realmente é muito mais código do que o que você implementou para resposta. Muito provavelmente quem deu upvote na outra resposta sabe o que cada método faz, o autor da pergunta se não me engano nem sequer pode votar ainda devido a pontuação baixa.